# Show that the sequence is bounded?

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Show that the sequence $\frac{3n + sin^2n}{6n}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded.

I know that $ 0 \leq sin^2n \leq 1$, so $\frac{3n}{6n} = \frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{3n + sin^2n}{6n} \leq \frac{3n + 1}{6n}$

So it is easy to see that it is bounded below by $\frac{1}{2}$, but I can't figure out how to show it is bounded above.

Comment: $\frac{3n + 1}{6n} = \frac{1 }{2}+\frac{ 1}{6n}$ and $\frac{ 1}{6n}$ can be bounded above

Comment: $\frac{3n+1}{6n}\le \frac{3n+n}{6n}=\frac{4}{6}$.

Comment: Well, it is kinda obvious. $1\leq 3n$ for example, therefore it is bounded by 1. Since $\frac{3n+1}{6n}\leq\frac{3n+3n}{6n}=1$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{3n}{6n} = \frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{3n + \sin^2n}{6n} \leq \frac{3n + 1}{6n}$

$\frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{3n + \sin^2n}{6n} \leq \frac{3n}{6n}+\frac{1}{6n}$

$\frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{3n + \sin^2n}{6n} \leq \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6n}\leq\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}$

In the last step I used the property that $1/6n$ is decreasing for all $n$ and hence has a maximum for $n=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac {3n+1}{6n}=\frac {3 +1/n}{6} < \frac 4 6 = 2/3$

Comment: Or 3n +1 <= 3n + n = 4n so ....

Comment: Shouldn't I be $\leq\frac46$?

Comment: Equality holds only if n = 1.  I was assuming n > 1 as $\frac {3 + sin^2 1}{6} < 2/3$.  But yeah, I just it should have been $\le$.